# Roots of modified polynomials

Tags: polynomials, na.numerical-analysis, cv.complex-variables, algebraic-equations

Consider the following two polynomials:

$$
g=x^3 - x^2 - (c + 2)x + c
$$

and

$$
h=x^3 - x^2 - cx + c
$$

The roots of $h$ are $1$ and $\pm \sqrt{c}$. I am interested in obtaining the roots of $g$, using the fact that $g=h-2x$.

Numerical calculation indicates that the roots of $g$ are indeed not very far from those of $h$. For example, the largest root of $g$ is $\sqrt{c}+\Theta(\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}})$.

In this example, I can derive such formulas using elementary methods but I wonder if there is a principled way to derive them.

Answer (score 4):

I guess, Chapter 2, §1 of ["Perturbation Theory of Linear Operators"](http://books.google.de/books?id=8ji2kN_D3BwC&lpg=PA63&dq=perturbation%20theory%20eigenvalues&hl=de&pg=PA62#v=onepage&q=perturbation%20theory%20eigenvalues&f=false) by Kato will answer your question.

Comment: I am not so sure, actually. Please note that I was asking about *modified* rather than *perturbed* polynomials, for a reason: the difference between $g$ and $h$ is not assumed to be small.

Answer (score 1):

*Ten years too late and too long for a comment.*

It is a bit more convenient to let $c=d^2$

Let $x_i$ the roots of $g=0$ with $(x_1>x_2>x_ 3)$

We have
$$x_1=d+\frac{1}{d} \left(1+\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{2
   d^2}-\frac{1}{d^3}-\frac{3}{d^4}+O\left(\frac
   {1}{d^5}\right)\right)$$
$$x_2=1-\frac 2 {d^2} \left(1-\frac{1}{d^2}-\frac{3}{d^4} +O\left(\frac{1}{d^{6}}\right)\right)$$
$$x_3=-d -\frac{1}{d} \left(1-\frac{1}{d}+\frac{1}{2
   d^2}+\frac{1}{d^3}-\frac{3}{d^4}+O\left(\frac
   {1}{d^5}\right)\right)$$

Trying for $c=12.345$, this would give
$$x_1=3.87853 \quad \quad x_2=0.85430 \quad\quad x_3=-3.72964$$ while the exact solutions are
$$x_1=3.87813\quad \quad x_2=0.85313 \quad\quad x_3=-3.73126 $$

For $g$, using the above truncated series, the errors are $\left\{\frac{6}{d^4},-\frac{30}{d^6},\frac{6}{d^4}\right\}$.